# EclipseLink's @UuidGenerator leads to NullPointerException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, eclipselink, uuid

I've tried to start using EclipseLink's @UuidGenerator annonation for ID generation but it failed with NPE.

I'm using Java EE 6 + GlassFish 4.1. Entity were created from servlet. EclipseLink version is 2.6.0-M3. Simple long id "@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)" works fine.

Entity code:

```
@Entity
@UuidGenerator(name="QUANTITY_GEN")
public class Quantity implements Serializable 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "QUANTITY_GEN")
    private String id;

...

}
```

Servlet code:

```
@WebServlet(name = "Qtest", urlPatterns =
{
    "/Qtest"
})
public class Qtest extends HttpServlet
{
    @EJB
    private QuantityFacade quantityFacade;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        ...

        Quantity qt = new Quantity();
        quantityFacade.create(qt);

        ...
    }
}
```

Trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sequencing.SequencingManager.getNextValue(SequencingManager.java:1067)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sequencing.ClientSessionSequencing.getNextValue(ClientSessionSequencing.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.assignSequenceNumber(ObjectBuilder.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.assignSequenceNumber(ObjectBuilder.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.assignSequenceNumber(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4290)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4235)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:287)
    at uuidtest.AbstractFacade.create(AbstractFacade.java:24)
```

Please advise maybe there is some obvious error?

Comment: Actually this @UuidGenerator seems to be not in great demand. It's badly documented and generates only String representation without possibility to use UUID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems it's really EclipseLink's bug and it will hardly be fixed soon so I've used a work around - direct id generation as described here http://blog.xebia.com/2009/06/03/jpa-implementation-patterns-using-uuids-as-primary-keys/

```
@Id
private String id;

public AbstractBaseEntity() {
    this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used following code to get rid of the issue. Using a default constructor gave me problems in cloning entities with composite keys while using BeanUtils.copyProperties(). Hence i used @PrePersist. This is called just before a row is created in database for the first time

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
public abstract class AbstractMasterUUIDEntity extends AbstractMasterEntity<String> {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @PrePersist
    public void generateId() {
        if(this.id == null ) {
            this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        }
    }

}
```